# Picture intermittently unavailable when posting to Pinterest via Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, api, pinterest

Pinterest's help site suggested I ask this question here.

I'm seeing an inconsistent behavior when pinning an image to Pinterest.
All of the thumbnails are available immediately, but when clicking on a pin, the main image is intermittently unavailable.

When I inspect the element:
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/58/d2/9a/58d29a5cd40835b94f4990f8e801b6d5.jpg

Gives me a "Access Denied" error.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>20BE26BCF865CAF5</RequestId>
<HostId>
u5ebnl1GD5OuCHRXIuzLZ5qPT/a8pevoR0aour8Ey+Ue8bXHD38oFeAswqmC25ngcLPLXo2Eg8k=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I haven't been able to determine the pattern.

Am I using the API wrong?
I'm making a call to the Javascript API.
This is successfully creating a pin on a user's board.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.pinterest.com/sdk/sdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PinterestShare() {
        var url = GetImageUrl();
        var description = GetDescription();
        var link = GetLink();
        var appId = GetAppId();

        PDK.init({ appId: appId, cookie: false });

        PDK.pin(url, description, link);
        };
</script>
```

I would appreciate any insight. Thanks in advance.

**Edit: 3/10/2016**

So I changed our implementation to use a different Pinterest API.
I'm seeing the same error with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PinterestShare() {
        var url = GetImageUrl();
        var description = GetDescription();
        var link = GetLink();

        PinUtils.pinOne({
            'url': link,
            'media': url,
            'description': description
        });

        };
</script>
```

This is what our users see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TurBV.jpg

Using sdk.js and PDK.pin(), there is a 15-40 minute delay before our image is visible on Pinterest.com.

Using pinit.js and PinUtils.pinOne(), there is a 1-5 minute delay before our image is visible on Pinterest.com

Comment: Intermittently as in it shows up if you wait a bit?

Comment: shriek, yeah it shows up either immediately or as late as an hour later.